# Can I use the same function delegate in a Parallel.For Loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, pointer-to-member, parallel.for

Is it possible to use the same function delegate in a Parallel.For loop or do I run in a deadlock.

This means I would like to do something like this:

```
    public Execute(float[] input, Func<float, int, bool> WorkOnIt)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, input.GetLength(0), i =>
        {
            if(WorkOnit(input, i)
               ...
            ...
         });
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same function, but be aware, that if you need to use data declared outside the function scope, you will need to ensure thread safety for these data types, e.g. use locking.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: so of course you can generate a deadlock by using parallel tasks, if you think of smtg like this:

```
void myfunction(...) {
   lock (locker) {
       doSomethingWithAGlobalList(..);
       waitForOtherTasksDoingThingsWithThatList(..);
   }
}
```

But this is not a matter of your Parallel.For and would be caused by any concurrent threads entering myfunction

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You are absolutely right this should only give a deadlock as in your example. I'm not that familiar with delegates, so I was worried that in multi-threading this might somehow interfere. But it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the details of `WorkOnIt`. Do you use any means of synchronization for externally visible objects that you have to be careful. If not then you are safe.

For example if your `WorkOnIt` looks like:

```
private void MyWorkOnIt(float[] input, int idx)
{
    lock(input) { /* ... */ } // possible deadlock scenario
}
```

This could deadlock if the code that calls `Execute` locks on the same object:

```
lock(myInput)
{
    Execute(myInput, MyWorkOnIt);
}
```

In general I would try to make the delegates of parallel loops completely independent of any shared state. If I can't do - e.g. when I have to aggregate items - then I'll use one of the parallel loops which use a local state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! I'm only reading from the array so you are right this should not give me a deadlock. I'm not that familiar with delegates, so I was worried that in multi-threading this might somehow interfere. But it seems to work fine now.